# Deserialize json array of dictionaries in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an array of dictionaries that I've created in javascript. After serializing to json I get the following string :

```
[
    {
        "key": "60236",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "key": "60235",
        "value": "gdsfgdfsg"
    },
    {
        "key": "60237",
        "value": "1"
    }
]
```

I am having a hard time getting this deserialized into either a list or dictionary in c#.

I've tried:

```
Dictionary<int, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(Model.Json);
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: change the <int, string> to <string, string> and see if that solves the issue.  the key is defined between two quotation, that might be the issue

Answer (score 15):

There are several ways that you can extract your key/value pairs to construct a dictionary:

```
var dict = "[{\"key\":\"60236\",\"value\":\"1\"},  
             {\"key\":\"60235\",\"value\":\"gdsfgdfsg\"},
             {\"key\":\"60237\",\"value\":\"1\"}]";
```

Use `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>(dict)
                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Use a custom object that represents your pairs and then create a dictionary from your collection.

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Temp>>(dict);
var dictionary = output.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

public class Temp
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, if you're uncomfortable with using a custom "throwaway" object just for deserialization, you can take a tiny performance hit and use dynamic instead.

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(dict)
                                 .ToDictionary (x => (int)x.key, y => (string)y.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

what i suggest is for try to see what actually your json represent. You can create a class here on [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and the use this class/List of this class (depend on whether your json is in the form of array or simple class object).

Just pass type to **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject** class type part. for example

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class>>(json);
```

In your case is it just an array of Temp class

```
public class Temp
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Sp all you need is :-

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Temp>>(json);
```

**The you can convert this list to dictionary as suggested in other answer:-**

```
var dictionary = output.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

This always help me out. Hope it help you too.