# How to convert a JSON array string to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string which looks like:

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"Apple "},{"Id":"2","Name":"Orange "},{"Id":"3","Name":"Banana "}....]
```

How can I convert the JSON string to this format: `{"1":"Apple"},{"2":"Orange"},{"3","Banana"}...` so I can create dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"1":"Apple"},{"2":"Orange"},{"3","Banana"}
    };
```

Comment: Czech out JSON.NET and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Comment: Perhaps this can steer you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384599/deserialize-json-array-of-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually transform your original string to another format.

With the use of an intermediary class, as shown below, you can convert directly:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, string> tt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObject>>(@"[{""Id"":""1"",""Name"":""Apple ""},{""Id"":""2"",""Name"":""Orange ""},{""Id"":""3"",""Name"":""Banana ""}]").ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Name);

public class DataObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So what this does is first convert the Json array into a `List<DataObject>`, and then using the Linq `ToDictionary` operator we complete the job.

Hope this helps

Comment: Remove @ in the given string otherwise it will  encountered parsing issue.

Comment: @PankajGupta care to elaborate ?

Comment: i agree i gave wrong answer but when you use single quotes instead og using this ""id"" so we don't need to use @ .