# C# - Mapping JSON Values to List with numbers as IDs

Tags: c#, json

I have ran into an issue while pulling data down from an API (Not mine and I can't change the way its formatted) and then mapping that onto a C# List.

A small sample of the JSON looks like this *(There are thousands of records in the form_values section and thousands of records)*

**JSON Sample:**

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "status":"4",
         "version":5,
         "form_values":{
            "4015":"TextValue",
            "5919":"TextValue",
            "6127":"TextValue",
            "7868":"0",
            "q311":"TextValue",
            "r83b":"0"
         }
      }
   ],
   "current_page":1,
   "total_pages":1,
   "total_count":1,
   "per_page":12
}
```

Currently I am putting the JSON result into a strongly typed list with the following code *(This uses Newtonsoft.Json)*:

**C# JSON Deserialize to List**

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json_data);
```

It is in the **Data.cs** Class that I am having issues as C# will not allow a variable to start with a int.

What I have tried, with no success is using the `Runtime.Serilization DataMember` attribute.

**Data.cs**

```
        [DataMember(Name = "4015")]
        public string textfeild { get; set; }
```

**The Issue:**

This results in a null value being set regardless of data behind. All of the fields that start with a letter work fine, so I am confident my JSON is being written to the List correctly, just need a solution for these annoying ID's that start with a number!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Comment: Try this tool: https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/ with your JSON to generate the C# class, then try to deserialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, the first one is to use `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
public class FormValues
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "4015")]
    public string T4015 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "5919")]
    public string T5919 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "6127")]
    public string T6127 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "7868")]
    public string T7868 { get; set; }
    public string q311 { get; set; }
    public string r83b { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public FormValues form_values { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
}
```

The second one is to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` for your `form_values` property:

```
public class Record
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> form_values { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
}
```

If your `form_values` are not fixed, then you should stick with the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property for `form_values` as Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, string> form_values { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

 var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(dict)
                             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Use a custom object that represents your pairs and then create a dictionary from your collection.

```
  var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Temp>>(dict);
            var dictionary = output.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

            public class Temp
            {
                public string Key { get; set; }
                public string Value { get; set; }
            }
```

also you can get a reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384599/deserialize-json-array-of-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)